# Writing out an element with staxmate api

Tags: xml, stax, staxmate

I am using staxmate to write out an xml document. I want to write out xml elements with a prefix/namespace like "pre:elem". I can construct this manually as "pre" + ":" + "elem" and pass it on to the addElement method of staxmate api. But, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually constructing is not guaranteed to work, so it is not a good solution (which you probably knew already). The right way is to get a Namespace instance (with suggested prefix) and use that for writing. So, something like:

```
SMOutputDocument doc = ...;
SMNamespace ns = doc.getNamespace("http://mynamespaces.com", "pre");
SMOutputElement elem = doc.addElement(ns, "root");
// ... and so forth
```

You can get namespace instances from any container (SMOutputDocument, SMOutputElement).

Without passing namespace object, default is to assume namespace with URI "" (which must be bound to no-prefix).

(note: I'll ask this to be added to [StaxMate FAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/StaxMateFAQ))